# Well-Defined Maps on Equivalence Classes of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a unitary commutative ring such that $1 \neq 0$ and $S \subseteq R$ be closed under multiplication (i.e. $\forall x,y \epsilon S, xy \epsilon S$) and contain 1. We define the relation $E$ on $R$ x $S$ by $(a,s)E(b,t)$ if and only if there exists $x \epsilon S$ such that $xat = xbs.$

1. Let $R_S$ be the set of $E$-classes. If $(a, s)$ $\epsilon$ $D$ x $S$, we denote by $\bar{(a, s)}$ $\epsilon$ $R_S$ the $E$-class of $(a, s)$. Show that the map $(\bar{(a,s)},\bar{(b,t)}\to \bar{(ab,st)}$ is well-defined.
2. Show that the map $(\bar{(a,s)},\bar{(b,t)}\to \bar{(at+bs,st)}$ is well-defined.

---

I'm really confused as to how to prove a map is well-defined. I think it means that the map holds regardless of the choice of a, b, s, and t but how do you prove that? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $D$ here?

Comment: @Mankind oops, typo. I meant $R$ x $S$.  I'll fix it now.

Comment: By the way, this process is called localization. You are formally inverting elements of $S$, and a pair $(r,s) \in R \times S$ corresponds to a fraction $r/s$. Note that the map in 1. is just multiplication of two fractions, and the map in 2. is just addition of two fractions.

Comment: @AlexProvost I think this would be useful for another part of this problem, proving that ($R_S$, (2), (1)) is a unitary commutative ring. Am I allowed to assume that (2) is the addition operation and (1) is the multiplication operation? I think I know how to prove that the ring is commutative ($R$ and $S$ are both commutative, therefore the elements in their $E$-classes can be rearranged?) but I'm not sure how to prove that it's unitary. How would I define the "unit" equivalence class?

Comment: @mil10 Yes, those are definitely the operations you want to use as addition and multiplication! (You do want to check the axioms, though.)

Comment: @mil10 To push you in the right direction for the second question: think as a fraction $r/s$ as the same thing as an equivalence class $\overline{(r,s)}$. With this in mind, what is the usual "unit" for a fraction? In other words, what $u,v$ could you choose such that $(u/v)(r/s) = (r/s)(u/v) = r/s$ for all $r,s$? (Recall that $R$ itself is unitary!) Notice that there is more than one possible choice for the pair $(u,v)$, and then show that all these pairs yield the same "unit" equivalence class $\overline{(u,v)}$.

Comment: @AlexProvost I see what you mean now. That means $\overline{(u, u)}$ would be the unit, with $u$ being an element of $S$? And to prove that it's $\overline{(u, u)}$ I can just show that two arbitrary elements of $S$, say $v$ and $w$, and show $(v, v)$E$(w,w)$? In that case, why do we need to know that $R$ is unitary? Also, which axioms should I check when applying these operations as addition and multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right general idea about what it means. Let’s look at the first one. To show that the map

$$\left\langle\overline{\langle a,s\rangle},\overline{\langle b,t\rangle}\right\rangle\mapsto\overline{\langle ab,st\rangle}$$

is well-defined, you must show that if $\langle a,s\rangle\mathrel{E}\langle a',s'\rangle$ and $\langle b,t\rangle\mathrel{E}\langle b',t'\rangle$, so that $\overline{\langle a,s\rangle}=\overline{\langle a',s'\rangle}$ and $\overline{\langle b,t\rangle}=\overline{\langle b',t'\rangle}$, then $\overline{\langle ab,st\rangle}=\overline{\langle a'b',s't'\rangle}$, i.e., $\langle ab,st\rangle\mathrel{E}\langle a'b',s't'\rangle$. In other words, we want to show that the operation yields the same result no matter which names for the arguments we use.

To do this, assume that $\langle a,s\rangle\mathrel{E}\langle a',s'\rangle$ and $\langle b,t\rangle\mathrel{E}\langle b',t'\rangle$; by definition this means that there are $x,y\in S$ such that $xas'=xa's$ and $ybt'=yb't$. We want to show that there is a $z\in S$ such that

$$z(ab)(s't')=z(a'b')(st)\;;\tag{1}$$

can you use $x$ and $y$ to find a $z\in S$ satisfying $(1)$?

You can use the same general approach for the second one.

Comment: Am I allowed to substitute $a = {xa's}/{xs'}$ and $b = {yb't}/{yt'}$ into (1) to solve this? With a lot of cancellation, that would show that z could be anything. Am I allowed to cancel?

Comment: @mil10: The expressions $xa's/xs'$ and $yb't/ty'$ are meaningless: no notion of division or fraction is available in the ring $R$. And you cannot in general cancel unless you have multiplicative inverses, which you in this case you do not. There is a specific $z\in R$ that can be defined very simply in terms of $x$ and $y$ that makes $(1)$ true.